# UNCONFIRMED BTC TRANSACTION SINCE 6 DAYS

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have an unconfirmed transaction since Wednesday, January 3rd 2018, 16:33:19 -05:00
BITCOIN TRANSACTION
2e39a1ff4843d429ebc1bca3f569791a5fa2f1df6b2177d490c0df2c771e80f9

It's 2.999 BTC  What can I do to have back my BTC?
I wanted to send these 3 BTC (2,999 without fees) from a my wallet to another my wallet, but that trasaction is stucked since Jan 3rd, so since 7 days!!
May somebody help me, I would be very grateful.
If you need more info please ask.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the time series of the mempool data](https://dedi.jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#) I can see that transactions with <150 sat/B are stuck since Jan 2nd.

Fortunately, after ~2 weeks your funds will be returned back, then you can rebroadcast it with a higher fee. You can also bump the fee of a stuck TX using a [fee bumping technique](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fee_bumping).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think it's too complicate for me. If you want to help me I will pay for. Tell me If you may.

Comment: Sure I can help. sahabi at gmail.